# How to find if words are close to each and with the same ending letters, and put comma? (JTextArea)

Tags: java, swing, find, jtextarea

Firstly i don't know if it's even possible. Well, I need a code which would find if in JTextArea are two or more word close to each other with the same ending (with the same two or more last letters) and auto put comma between them. For ex. "I walked played with my dog" it should fix that sentence to: "I walked, played with my dog" it should auto put comma between walked and played because they're close to each other and two last letters are the same. Can anyone help me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex based solution:

```
String inputString = "I walked played with bobby robby my dog";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z]{2})\\s([a-z]{0,})\\1");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
while (m.find()) {
    inputString = inputString.substring(0, m.start(2) - 1) + ", " + inputString.substring(m.start(2));
    m = p.matcher(inputString);
}
```

The pattern searches for places where there are 2 letters, a space, then some more letters, then the first 2 letters again.

I tweaked the input string to prove it was working, and my output was as expected:

'I walked played with bobby robby my dog'

becomes:

'I walked, played with bobby, robby my dog'

addition: In order to increase the number of characters matched, increase the number in {2} to the desired value. If there is one specific pair you are looking for (e.g. ed) then change [a-z]{2} to be your desired characters. e.g.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(ed)\\s([a-z]{0,})\\1");
```

Comment: How to print fix into jtextarea?

Comment: once you've done that you would use this: textArea1.setText(inputString); or something along these lines depending on the name of your textArea

Comment: Thank you so much! But one quostion. What if need to add more ending letter for e.x. "played played name name" its should fix to "played, played name, name"?

Comment: the code above does that transformation. "played played name name" becomes "played, played name, name". Not sure what you're asking for now? (p.s. if my solution works, mark the question as solved, accept the answer to mark it as solved :D)

Comment: Ok, I'll mark :D. But what if I want commas just for two particular endings like "me" or "ed".

Comment: seperate them with a | (pipe) like this, this means it will only happen where 2 words both end in ed or me. Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(ed|me)\\s([a-z]{0,})\\1");

Comment: Thank you again one more time. But I have one last question :D. What if i want sometimes to put commas between ending "ed" and "me" if needed.

Comment: try this: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(ed|me)\\s([a-z]{0,})(ed|me)");

Comment: Sorry I was on my phone so I didn't ask properly. So what if I want comma on endings "ed" and "me", but also want comma on endings "de" and "em" (By the way it's putting comma between "ed" and "me", but not putting between "me" and "ed"). Sorry for my silly questions. I'm new on programming :). Thanks

Comment: add them in to these parts: (ed|me) so, (ed|me|de|em), the more and more you add though, the less appropriate the solution is. Really the question should have been: put a comma between 2 words which end in one of a list of values. For this, i wouldn't have used regex.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me good. for ex. I use this code:
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(ed|me)\\s([a-z]{0,})(ed|me)");` and when I type: "played name" it's gonna be "played, name" but what if I want "played, name and name, played" or "played, name and house, plain"?

Comment: played name and name played should work with that regex. house plain won't. you're know in the realms of putting a comma between every word. unless you have a definitive list of word endings you want seperated by a comma, this isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
// First read the text from the text area:
String text = textArea1.getText();

// Split the string around spaces (thats enough based on your specification above)
String[] words = text.split(" ");

String lastLetters = "";

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

// Go through building up the result by looking at one word at a time
for (String str: words) {
  if (!lastLetters.isEmpty() && str.endsWith(lastLetters) {
     result.append(", ");
  } else {
     result.append(" ");
  }
  result.append(str);
  int start = str.length()-3;
  if (start < 0) {
     start = 0;
  }
  lastLetters = str.substring(start, str.length()-1);
}

// Set the result into the other text area
textArea2.setText(result.toString());
```

You might need to tweak some of the parameters into the subString to get the exact range of values you need, etc.

Comment: You made couple mistakes: `endsWith` and `sunstring`. When i fixed it it just putted space in the beginning. What if I know what the last two letters should be?

Comment: Fixed the typos. I don't understand what you mean after that though?

Comment: When i type: "played played" it's fixing: ", played played".